# Pass static library name (-I) and its path (-L) to cmake from command line

Tags: build, cmake

I want to pass a library name (in gcc, `-l` option) and its path (in gcc `-L` option
) to cmake. How I can do it?

I tried it with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, but those seem to be used to pass compiler flags. They are not for library flags. How I could pass the library path (`-L`) and its name (`-l`) from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` variables, but in most cases you don't need to specify these.

If the project you are building require some libraries, you have to list them in `target_link_libraries()` call somewhere in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: How should I pass flags actually? If I want to specify a library `libmycode.a` in `/home/username/opt/lib`,`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L/home/username/opt/lib -lmycode"` is correct?